# Retrieve file object from FileReader.result to send to server as ajax data

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, filereader

My question is simple:

```
var picReader = new FileReader();
picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){
    var picFile = event.target;
    // I assign picFile.result to an <img>'s src attribute
    <img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'/>";
}
//Read the image
picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Later when I do not have access to actual FileReader and have access to only `<img>` in jquery, **how can I send this image(img.src) as data to server.** Server code is in ASP.NET MVC and is expacting a `HttpPostedFileBase` object in controller.

If I use 'img.src' as data in `$.ajax`, it DOES NOT send file as `Request.File`, It appends data in request param.

**Background**

I am trying to build a multiple image upload feature with preview in a div. User can click a button to remove any selected image from div, but that image file cannot be removed from Files list(`<input type=file>`) as `Files` object is readonly. So to get final list of images I have to depend upon the `<img>` tag inside the preview div. User might have selected 5 images initially, which means

event.target.files; //FileList object contains 5 file objects

But after seeing preview he only wants to upload 3 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think this would help?

[How to send FormData objects with Ajax-requests in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery/8244082#8244082)

Basically converting the image to FormData object before sending it via ajax?